# Insert Content Controls Word add-in on search

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js, add-in, office-addins

I have some keywords already present in my Word document, which I want to be able to search and if found, insert Content Controls on that specific keyword. Something like -

```
let searchResults = context.document.body.search("[[]*[]]", { matchWildCards: true });
context.load(searchResults, 'text');
let contentControl = searchResults.items[0].text.insertContentControl();
```

Is there any way to do this?
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can do that although your syntax isn't quite right. (It's the Range object that has the insertContentControl method, not `text`. See [insertContentControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.range?view=word-js-preview#insertcontentcontrol--). This will wrap the keyword in a rich content control.